# Replacing a part from the string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string like below:

```
string str = "Key=abc;arg=pqr;lock=100;timeout=1;"
```

Now I replace this part from the string:

```
arg=pqr;
```

So my final string will be like below:

```
string final ="Key=abc;lock=100;timeout=1;"
```

I have tried like below:

```
string final = str.Replace("arg=pqr;", "");
```

But the problem is when `pqr` changes to something else like `Lmn` then it will not work.

Comment: How do you determine whether `pqr` or `lmn` or something else? what ever it may, get it in a variable and perform replace

Comment: Why don't you try this: Parse the data (the format seems pretty easy), look for the one that starts with `arg=???` and put it together again.

Comment: Downvoters what made you vote for downvoting.what wrong did you find in this question.please care to comment so that i can be aware next time while asking question.sometimes it is hard to ask a question on SO because i dont know which question will be welcomed and which will not

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with your question, so I gave it an upvote to compensate somewhat for the downvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using *regular expressions* in order to replace pattern: `"arg="` followed by *alphanumeric value* with `;`:

```
  string str = "Key=abc;arg=pqr;lock=100;timeout=1;";

  string final = Regex.Replace(str, @"arg=[0-9a-zA-Z]*;", "");
```

In general case you can implement a method like this:

```
  private static string RemoveRecord(string source, string name) {
    string pattern = @"(?<!\w)" + Regex.Escape(name) + "=[0-9a-zA-Z]*;";

    return Regex.Replace(source, pattern, "");
  }

  ...

  string final = RemoveRecord("Key=abc;arg=pqr;lock=100;timeout=1;", "arg");
```

Comment: Suppose if i have arg like this : arg=1pqr or arg=pqr1 then??

Comment: @Learning: then change the pattern a bit: `@"arg=[0-9a-zA-Z]*;"`

Comment: What's the difference's?

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran: I've added `0-9` range to existed one `a-zA-Z`

Comment: I think the OP asked, the string value is dynamically changing.

Comment: Yes this worked.thank you so much and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: @Learning: you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you

```
string cm = "Key=abc;arg=pqr;lock=100;timeout=1;";
string finalstr = Regex.Replace(cm, "arg=[^;]*;", "");
```

if you dont know what would be after `arg=` and before `;`

Comment: Maybe include the `=`, in case there is an argument `arg2`

Comment: Hey @ManfredRadlwimmer that is a nice suggestion. Lemme update the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, regular expressions is a natural for this one. (One caveat would be the handling of semicolons, but since you appear to have a terminating semicolon anyway, the regular expression can assume that all key/value pairs end with one, and thus the problem doesn't arise in this particular case.)

Here is another approach that doesn't use regular expressions, but hacks the string apart and puts it back together:

```
string str = "Key=abc;arg=Lmn;lock=100;timeout=1;";
str = RemoveArg(str);
// str == "Key=abc;lock=100;timeout=1;"
...
private static string RemoveArg(string str)
{
    string[] originalKeyValuePairs = str.Split(';');
    List<string> newKeyValuePairs = new List<string>();
    foreach (var keyValuePair in originalKeyValuePairs)
    {
        string[] splitKeyValuePair = keyValuePair.Split('=');
        if (splitKeyValuePair[0] != "arg")
        {
            newKeyValuePairs.Add(keyValuePair);
        }
    }

    return string.Join(";", newKeyValuePairs);
}
```

In the above you could easily make `"arg"` a parameter for greater flexibility. If you don't need that flexibility, you could simplify the loop even more:

```
foreach (var keyValuePair in originalKeyValuePairs)
{
    if (!keyValuePair.StartsWith("arg="))
    {
        newKeyValuePairs.Add(keyValuePair);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and i am gald to receive answer from microsoft developer :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is remove `string` with `split` and `join` if you don't want to use `Regex`

```
string str = "Key=abc;arg=pqr;lock=100;timeout=1;";

var strUpdated = string.Join("arg=Lmn;", str.Split(new[] { "arg=pqr;" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

and the output will be

```
Key=abc;arg=Lmn;lock=100;timeout=1;
```

and if you want to remove the string then simply replace `"arg=Lmn;"` with `""`

Comment: The OP wants to replace `"arg=???"` -- it might be `"arg=pqr"`, but it might also be `"arg=Lmn"`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to replace string

```
        string _originalstr = "Key=abc;arg=pqr;lock=100;timeout=1;";

        var _newString = string.Join(";", _originalstr.Split(';').Where(x => x.Contains("arg") == false));
```